# "Access to the path XXX is denied" SSIS package execution from SQL query (for File System Task)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm trying to execute a package that among other thing after processing an xlsx in a folder, it deletes it. for this, when executing from visual studio it works fine, the problem comes when executing from sql server (by using script to run it):

```
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'ImportAllowanceWood.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, @folder_name=N'Packages', @project_name=N'JSTEMS_Payroll_Import', @use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=Null
Select @execution_id
DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', @parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=30, @parameter_name=N'Payroll', @parameter_value=N'B00014552'
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
GO
```

the error I'm getting is
[image]

and I'm think it might be related to permission on the folder in which I want to operate.

in the folder I gave full permission to the sql server agent, the my domain user (which is used when running the query), "NETWORK SERVICE" and "everyone".

but I still get the error, is there any specific user I should give permission?

I've seen around to grant permission to

- NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT
- NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER

but I don't know how to do it, since when looking for them in the permission folder they are not found

Comment: Sounds like the old "double hop" issue. Speak to your network administrator to ensure that kerboros is enabled to allow "double hopping".

Comment: I'm investigating on this, I have access to both servers as admin, so I should be able to set it

Comment: To elaborate on my point here, this scenario is specific to when running the job using SQL, it won't happen via Agent. When running via Agent the agent runs the package directly, meaning that calls to the file system are direct from the connecting application (the package). For when you run it via SQL, this isn't the case. The user (you) connects the the SQL Server, which then calls the package, which (asynchronously in this example) calls the file system. SQL->Package->File System, hence the "double hop" and hence without the correct settings the call the to file is made anonymously.

Comment: I think you might be right, when executing from SQL Server agent it does do the file manipulation in destination folder., so yes, the issue seems to only happen when running from SQL (which I need since I have a front end that needs to trigger the call)

Comment: @Larnu - when executed via SQL, before execution starts, the user is already authenticated. So I am findng it difficult to imagine how is it then becomes a double hop. Can you advise please. Also, had user done right click on package and execute (this running in context of user connected to management studio) then also would it be a double hop problem?